# Get data from an another webpage

Tags: php

I want to to extract buy and sell value from [this](https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all) website

How can I do this using file_get_contents() in PHP

For e.g

```
$abc  = file_get_content("https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all");
```

Now how can I extract buy and sell value from it in every 2 min?

Comment: What you have done so far to extract the info you needed ?

Comment: I just don't know how to extract data form another page.

Comment: this is called _scraping_ . A google search will get you tons of ways to do so

Answer (score 1):

Here if you want to extract data from other webpage than you use `php curl`

**Example**

```
function curl_download($Url){

    // is cURL installed yet?
    if (!function_exists('curl_init')){
        die('Sorry cURL is not installed!');
    }

    // OK cool - then let's create a new cURL resource handle
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Now set some options (most are optional)

    // Set URL to download
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $Url);

    // Include header in result? (0 = yes, 1 = no)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    // Should cURL return or print out the data? (true = return, false = print)
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Timeout in seconds
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    // Download the given URL, and return output
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close the cURL resource, and free system resources
    curl_close($ch);

    return $output;
}

print curl_download('https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all');
```

Answer (score 0):

For this particular site, the data is json encoded so all you need to do is and it does not seem to have any further authentication requirement, as I can just get to the link and see the data.

```
$abc  = file_get_content("https://www.unocoin.com/trade?all");
$decoded_abc=json_decode($abc);
$buy=$decoded_abc->buy;
$sell=$decoded_abc->sell;
```